# How to add a static value against each row that is created by a loop in python3?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
district_name= [[li.getText() for li in data_rows[i].findAll('li')]
               for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```

Above code gives us a list of district names of a state Bihar. Somthing like below table.

```
[['1', 'Nalanda'],
 ['2', 'Patna'],
 ['3', 'Gaya'],
 ['4', 'Buxer']]
```

But I want to add a static element "Bihar" againest each row. somthing like below.

```
[['1', 'Bihar', 'Nalanda'],
 ['2', 'Bihar', 'Patna'],
 ['3', 'Bihar', 'Gaya'],
 ['4', 'Bihar', 'Buxer']]
```

I tried to achive that by using code  `district_name.insert(0,'Bihar')`. but it does not give the expect result. it give us.

```
['Bihar',['1',  'Nalanda'],
 ['2', 'Patna'],
 ['3', 'Gaya'],
 ['4', 'Buxer']]
```

Plese help me on this.

Comment: You should look at JSON formatting. It will give you a much better data structure than what you have written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check This Code out:

```
x = [['1', 'Nalanda'], ['2', 'Patna'],  ['3', 'Gaya'], ['4', 'Buxer']]

for i in range(len(x)):
     x[i].insert(1,'Bihar')

print(x)
```

district_name.insert(0,'Bihar') will result in inserting Bihar as the first element of district_name.
But your intention is different. You want it to be inserted in 1st position of each list inside the list.

so you might have to do

```
 for i in range(len(x)):
      district_name[i].insert(1,'Bihar')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the `district_name` list and insert 'Bihar' position 1 in every list.

```
district_name= [[li.getText() for li in data_rows[i].findAll('li')]
               for i in range(len(data_rows))]

y = [district_name[index].insert(1,'Bihar') for index in range(len(district_name))]

print district_name
```